# Vcpkg Visual Studio re-export headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

I've got two types of projects in Visual Studio.

1. A generator project, containing .proto files, the generated .pb.h files, and other generated files.
2. My actual projects. I have about 10 of those.

The generator project has a VCPKG manifest, and depends on grpc.
My actual project references the generator project, and includes the .pb.h files.

I can build the generator project just fine, but my actual projects, when including the .pb.h files, fail to find `#include<grpcpp/impl/...>`

I'd rather not add grpc as a dependency to every project. I'd prefer having generator as a reference to handle this. My main reason for this would be that it complicates updating grpc, as all packages would have to reference a compatible baseline-manifest. Also, having both a reference to my generator project and a VCPKG dependency to grpc sounds... double.

I would be willing to add my generator project as a VCPKG dependency to all other projects. If I'm not mistaken, then I should remove the reference, build a local package overlay, and manually package my generator project each time it changes. Not ideal either.

What would be the best approach to set this up? Is there a way to let my generator project re-export the headers of grpc, so my projects can find them from there? (This is how I used to do it when I was building grpc manually. It worked perfectly fine, but updating was a pain. That's why I'm looking into switching to VCPKG.)

Edit: for reference, here's a myprotofile.grpc.pb.h:

```
// Generated by the gRPC C++ plugin.
// If you make any local change, they will be lost.
// source: myprotofile.proto
#ifndef GRPC_myprotofile_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define GRPC_myprotofile_2eproto__INCLUDED

#include "myprotofile.pb.h"

#include <functional>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_generic_service.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_context.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/message_allocator.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/method_handler.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/proto_utils.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_method.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback_handlers.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_context.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/service_type.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/status.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/stub_options.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/sync_stream.h>

namespace proto {
}  // namespace proto


#endif  // GRPC_myprotofile_2eproto__INCLUDED
```

You can see the includes. As pointed out by @HansPassant it's "odd" that they are including internals here, but as that's how grpc works, I'll just have to deal with it.

Edit: please come on people, just help me instead of suggesting all kinds of stupid patterns. I've been developing for multiple decades, you will not be helping me with simply saying "you need pimpl" or stupid patterns like that. Grpc generates code, I use that code.

I'm only new to VCPKG. Help me with that, instead of trying to shove your view down my throat based on the limited description of my architecture I can give here.

Comment: The generated .pb.h file(s) are leaking implementation details.  Don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant it would be of more use to me too know what I should be doing then, instead of just what not to.

Comment: It would be more use to us to know how those implementation details got leaked.  Doesn't make much sense that grpc appears in .h file declarations.

Comment: Have you ever generated a grpc pb header file? They contain a lot of references to grpc internals. Not exactly something I can fix.

Comment: I could of course let every project generate it's own .grpc.pb.h files, but that would only mean even more work and would mean I'd still need grpc in every project. If those headers shouldn't include references to the grpc library, that should be brought up to the grpc project and not here imo. I'm just consuming grpc as it is, and trying to work with it the best I can.

Comment: @HansPassant I added a example. Do you have any recommendations on how to deal with "them" (grpc) exposing their privates?

Comment: @AhmedAEK are you telling me to rewrite protoc? I'll repeat, not my code. It's generated.

Comment: So for all code that's generated, you manually write extra code, is what you're suggesting? Since when did this community get so pushy on their own ideas, instead of attempting to help people?